# Ampersands replaced by slashes in JSONP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jsonp

I have problem fetching information from database. When I out put it as JSONP using this code:

```
$json = json_encode($data);

echo isset($_GET['callback'])
    ? "{$_GET['callback']}($json)"
    : $json;
```

It interpretates all `&`signs as: `\/` So instead of "Food & Water" it becomes "Food / Water". Can anyone hint me where is the problem?

Comment: My first guess would be that the problem lies inside json_encode()

Comment: What does your `callback` do?

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of the incorrect output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it, but not why it happens. Basically I stripped backslashes and then replaced all forward slashes with & like this:

```
$json = json_encode($columns);

$json = stripslashes($json);
$json = str_replace("/","&", $json);


echo isset($_GET['callback'])
    ? "{$_GET['callback']}($json)"
    : $json;
```

And it worked the way I wanted. Hope it helps other people who have same issue.

Comment: Could you post the raw input please in your post?